# CSS: The hover does not quit even after the mouse is lifted

Tags: html, css

my problem is that if I hover over a link, the background changes as I would like it to. However when I move to the next link, it stays that way and if I move to the last link, all the links look like they are on hover. But they all return to normal if i remove the mouse off the links. It's like a step sequence. If link 1 is hovered, only link 1 is affected. If link 2 is hovered, anything above link 2 is also hovered and same for link 3. Anything above link 3 will be hovered. How can I fix this so it is going to hover individually? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks. This is my CSS code:

```
#profilebarsectiondiv {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #285059;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.profilebarlink{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #dce8ea;
}

.profilebarlink a{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #206676;
}

.profilebarlink:hover{
    background-color: #e67e17;
}
```

And my HTML

```
<div id="profilebarsectiondiv">Dashboard</div>
<div class="profilebarlink"><a href="#">Home</a>
<div class="profilebarlink"><a href="#">Profile</a>
<div class="profilebarlink"><a href="#">Contacts</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close your `<div>` tags

```
<div id="profilebarsectiondiv">Dashboard</div>
<div class="profilebarlink"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
<div class="profilebarlink"><a href="#">Profile</a></div>
<div class="profilebarlink"><a href="#">Contacts</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the all `<div>` tags. And you were applying to hover style on the `<div class="profilebarlink">`. But this method is not efficient.

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/tjyC2/) with the correction and the improvement in the code.

### HTML

```
<div id="profilebarsectiondiv">Dashboard</div>
<a href="#" class="profilebarlink">Home</a>
<a href="#" class="profilebarlink">Profile</a>
<a href="#" class="profilebarlink">Contacts</a>​
```

### CSS

```
#profilebarsectiondiv {
    background-color: #285059;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.profilebarlink{
    display: block;
    background-color: #dce8ea;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #206676;
}

.profilebarlink:hover{
    background-color: #e67e17;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your correct HTML

```
<div id="profilebarsectiondiv">Dashboard</div>
<div class="profilebarlink"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
<div class="profilebarlink"><a href="#">Profile</a></div>
<div class="profilebarlink"><a href="#">Contacts</a></div>
```

Div need closing tag also

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="profilebarsectiondiv">Dashboard</div>
<div class="profilebarlink"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
<div class="profilebarlink"><a href="#">Profile</a></div>
<div class="profilebarlink"><a href="#">Contacts</a></div>
```

bro close your div tags :), it will definitely work